# npm audit fix not fixing low vulnerability

Tags: npm, lodash, nightmare, npm-audit

I am using `nightmare` for testing.After running npm audit I get a warning about lodash Prototype pollution.I tried to fix this by running `npm audit fix` but no result.After that I tried using `--force` but still get :

```
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 2108 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

Any ideas how can I fix it?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.mariadcampbell.com/2018/06/05/the-new-npm-audit-with-npm-6/

Comment: I tried it but still nothing

Comment: And have you looked on the "More info" link listed in the manual review section? It looks like you need to manually update lodash to a higher version.

Comment: Yes I have looked at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` dependencies do not automatically get upgraded to a higher major version. So if package `A` depends on package `B` with a version specification such as:

```
// A/package.js
dependencies: {
  "B": "^2.1.3"
}
```

Then `npm` will keep `B` up to date for any version 2.x.y where x >= 1 and (y >= 3 if x == 1 or y >= 0 if x > 1).

However, if the security fix happened in `B` version 3.v.w, then the security issue is going to remain in your `npm` repository.

The problem here is that to be able to use version 3.v.w you may have to update `A` because it is likely that there are breaking changes between 2 and 3 (i.e. a function name changed or support for a certain property was removed.)

Here is an example of breaking changes in the [react-idle-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer) module:

## Migration from v3 to v4

There are a few breaking changes in version 4:

- Although still capable of rendering children, as of version 4 we don't pass children to `IdleTimer`. Unless you are really good with `shouldComponentUpdate` you should avoid using `IdleTimer` as a wrapper component.
- The property `startOnLoad` has been renamed to `startOnMount` in order to make more sense in a React context.
- The property `activeAction` has been renamed to `onActive`.
- The property `idleAction` has been renamed to `onIdle`.